# Counting '1' in number in C

Tags: c, binary

My task was to print all whole numbers from 2 to N(for which in binary amount of '1' is bigger than '0')

```
int CountOnes(unsigned int x)
{ 
    unsigned int iPassedNumber = x; // number to be modifed
    unsigned int iOriginalNumber = iPassedNumber;
    unsigned int iNumbOfOnes = 0;

    while (iPassedNumber > 0)
    {
        iPassedNumber = iPassedNumber >> 1 << 1;  //if LSB was '1', it turns to '0'

        if (iOriginalNumber - iPassedNumber == 1) //if diffrence == 1, then we increment numb of '1'
        {
            ++iNumbOfOnes;
        }

        iOriginalNumber = iPassedNumber >> 1; //do this to operate with the next bit
        iPassedNumber = iOriginalNumber; 
    }
    return (iNumbOfOnes);
}
```

Here is my function to calculate the number of '1' in binary. It was my homework in college. However, my teacher said that it would be more efficient to

```
{ 
   if(n%2==1)
      ++CountOnes;
   else(n%2==0)
      ++CountZeros;
}
```

In the end, I just messed up and don`t know what is better. What do you think about this?

Comment: Isn't 1 always bigger then 0? Confused.

Comment: how does one count zeroes? You mean zeroes *after* the most significant one?

Comment: @alk I guess this is about popcnt being > or >= than half of the width of the value.

Comment: else(n%2==0) does it compile? Maybe but definitelly not using the C compiler :D

Comment: say your tutor that & 1 will be more effective without the optimisations.

Comment: There is stuff missing from your teacher's suggestion (presumably it's a loop), and `(n%2==0)` should be a comment.

Comment: @harold, it was just a hint from my tutor. I thought it was a wrong suggestion.

Comment: `iPassedNumber = iPassedNumber >> 1 << 1` why don't simply use `iPassedNumber &= ~0u << 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used gcc compiler for the experiment below.  Your compiler may be different, so you may have to do things a bit differently to get a similar effect.

When trying to figure out the most optimized method for doing something you want to see what kind of code the compiler produces. Look at the CPU's manual and see which operations are fast and which are slow on that particular architecture. Although there are general guidelines. And of course if there are ways you can reduce the number of instructions that a CPU has to perform.

I decided to show you a few different methods (not exhaustive) and give you a sample of how to go about looking at optimization of small functions (like this one) manually. There are more sophisticated tools that help with larger and more complex functions, however this approach should work with pretty much anything:

## Note

All assembly code was produced using:

> gcc -O99 -o foo -fprofile-generate foo.c

followed by

> gcc -O99 -o foo -fprofile-use foo.c

### On -fprofile-generate

The double compile makes gcc really let's gcc work (although -O99 most likely does that already) however mileage may vary based on which version of gcc you may be using.

## On with it:

### Method I (you)

Here is the disassembly of your function:

```
CountOnes_you:
.LFB20:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        je      .L5
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        movl    %edi, %edx
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        andl    $-2, %edx
        subl    %edx, %edi
        cmpl    $1, %edi
        movl    %edx, %edi
        sete    %cl
        addl    %ecx, %eax
        shrl    %edi
        jne     .L4
        rep ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L5:
        rep ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

#### At a glance

Approximately 9 instructions in a loop, until the loop exits

### Method II (teacher)

Here is a function which uses your teacher's algo:

```
int CountOnes_teacher(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int one_count = 0;
    while(x) {
        if(x%2)
            ++one_count;
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return one_count;
}
```

Here's the disassembly of that:

```
CountOnes_teacher:
.LFB21:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        je      .L12
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L11:
        movl    %edi, %edx
        andl    $1, %edx
        cmpl    $1, %edx
        sbbl    $-1, %eax
        shrl    %edi
        jne     .L11
        rep ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L12:
        rep ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

#### At a glance:

5 instructions in a loop until the loop exits

### Method III

Here is Kernighan's method:

```
 int CountOnes_K(unsigned int x) {
      unsigned int count;
      for(count = 0; ; x; count++) {
          x &= x - 1; // clear least sig bit
      }
      return count;
 }
```

Here's the disassembly:

```
CountOnes_k:
.LFB22:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edi, %edi
        je      .L19
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L18: 
        leal    -1(%rdi), %edx
        addl    $1, %eax
        andl    %edx, %edi
        jne     .L18  ; loop is here
        rep ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L19:
        rep ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

#### At a glance

3 instructions in a loop.

### Some commentary before continuing

As you can see the compiler doesn't really use the *best* way when you employ `%` to count (which was used by both you and your teacher).

Krenighan method is pretty optimized, least number of operations in the loop).  It is instructional to compare Krenighan to the naive method of counting, while on the surface it may look the same it's really not!

```
for (c = 0; v; v >>= 1)
{
  c += v & 1;
}
```

This method sucks compared to Krenighans. Here if you have say the 32nd bit set this loop will run 32 times, whereas Krenighan's will not!

But all these methods are still rather sub-par because they loop.

If we combine a couple of other piece of (implicit) knowledge into our algorithms we can get rid of loops all together.  Those are, 1 the size of our number in bits, and the size of a character in bits. With these pieces and by realizing that we can filter out bits in chunks of 14, 24 or 32 bits given that we have a 64 bit register.

So for instance, if we look at a 14-bit number then we can simply count the bits by:

```
 (n * 0x200040008001ULL & 0x111111111111111ULL) % 0xf;
```

uses `%` but only once for all numbers between `0x0` and `0x3fff`

For 24 bits we use 14 bits and then something similar for the remaining 10 bits:

```
  ((n & 0xfff) * 0x1001001001001ULL & 0x84210842108421ULL) % 0x1f 
+ (((n & 0xfff000) >> 12) * 0x1001001001001ULL & 0x84210842108421ULL) 
 % 0x1f;
```

But we can generalize this concept by realizing the patterns in the numbers above and realize that the *magic numbers* are actually just compliments (look at the hex numbers closely 0x8000 + 0x400 + 0x200 + 0x1) shifted

We can generalize and then shrink the ideas here, giving us the most optimized method for counting bits (up to 128 bits) (no loops) O(1):

```
CountOnes_best(unsigned int n) {
    const unsigned char_bits = sizeof(unsigned char) << 3;
    typedef __typeof__(n) T; // T is unsigned int in this case;
    n = n - ((n >> 1) & (T)~(T)0/3); // reuse n as a temporary 
    n = (n & (T)~(T)0/15*3) + ((n >> 2) & (T)~(T)0/15*3);
    n = (n + (n >> 4)) & (T)~(T)0/255*15;
    return (T)(n * ((T)~(T)0/255)) >> (sizeof(T) - 1) * char_bits;
} 


CountOnes_best:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    %edi, %eax
        shrl    %eax
        andl    $1431655765, %eax
        subl    %eax, %edi
        movl    %edi, %edx
        shrl    $2, %edi
        andl    $858993459, %edx
        andl    $858993459, %edi
        addl    %edx, %edi
        movl    %edi, %ecx
        shrl    $4, %ecx
        addl    %edi, %ecx
        andl    $252645135, %ecx
        imull   $16843009, %ecx, %eax
        shrl    $24, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

This may be a bit of a jump from (how the heck did you go from previous to here), but just take your time to go over it.

The most optimized method was first mentioned in *Software Optimization Guide for AMD Athelon™ 64 and Opteron™ Processor*, my URL of that is broken. It is also well explained on the very excellent [C bit twiddling page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable%5D)

I highly recommend going over the content of that page it really is a fantastic read.

Comment: gcc `-O99` is not implemented and that optimization level is currently equivalent to `-O3`.

Comment: @Explorer09 yes... :-) -O99 is just a shorthand for optimize as much as possible so in the future if -O4 comes out -O99 will translate to -O4 .. etc

Comment: Higher optimization level doesn't always mean better code. GCC's `-O3` level is meant to "aggressively optimize for speed" and typically results in larger code than `-O2`. `-O3` is more for servers (with large memory and caches) or centain performance-critical pieces of code. `-O2` are for general distribution binaries. Compile everything in `-O3` is still a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Even better that your teacher's suggestion:

```
   if( n & 1 ) {
      ++ CountOnes;
   }
   else {
      ++ CountZeros;
   }
```

`n % 2` has an implicit divide operation which the compiler is likely to optimise, but you should not rely on it - divide is a complex operation that takes longer on some platforms.  Moreover there are only two options 1 or 0, so if it is not a one, it is a zero - there is no need for the second test in the `else` block.

Your original code is overcomplex and hard to follow.  If you want to assess the "efficiency" of an algorithm, consider the number of operations performed per iteration, and the number of iterations.  Also the number of variables involved.  In your case there are 10 operations per iteration and three variables (but you omitted to count the zeros so you'd need four variables to complete the assignment).  The following:

```
unsigned int n = x; // number to be modifed
int ones = 0 ;
int zeroes = 0 ;

while( i > 0 )
{
   if( (n & 1) != 0 )
   {
      ++ones ;
   }
   else
   {
      ++zeroes ;
   }

   n >>= 1 ;
}
```

has only 7 operations (counting `>>=` as two - *shift and assign*).  More importantly perhaps, it is much easier to follow.

Comment: it doesn't have 7 operations. It has as many operations as generated by the loop and OP was focusing on optimizing counting bits.

Comment: You don't need `something != 0` at all. Just write `something` and it saves two (or more) instructions (if not optimized).

Comment: @iBug : True, but in this case `(n & 1)` is an integer expression, so there is an implicit conversion to boolean whereas `(n & 1) != 0` is _explicitly_ boolean.  It is logically one fewer operations, but I doubt it will make any difference to the code generation in practice with or without optimisation (YMMV) since it is a trivial localised optimisation.  Personally however I wrote it that way because I work (for a living) under an enforced (by static analysis) coding standard that requires conditional expressions to be boolean.; so force of habit, and because it is good practice.

Comment: @AhmedMasud :  I am talking about _operations_ at the source level (i.e. counting the operators), not machine level _instructions_, which is I guess what you thought.  The intrinsic efficiency of the algorithm can be judged in that way independently of any specific instruction set or compiler optimisation.  Intrinsically efficient algorithms will generally lead to better compiler optimisation than a sloppy algorithm that relies on the compiler to "fix" it.  Moreover he was not focusing on optimising anything, he was merely canvassing opinion on the teacher's suggestion.

Comment: @AhmedMasud : The answer is not intended to necessarily be optimal, it rather describes an approach to comparing the likely efficiency of algorithms at the source level.  Its the compiler's job to optimise it to the target instruction set IMO.  When it is critical (and it very seldom is) comparing the compiled code efficiency (profiling) of different implementations may be necessary, but would most often be a _premature optimisation_.  This approach is more productive (a different measure of efficiency).